# How to use "où" and "d'où"?

Tags: questions

I'm doing an exercise of making questions. Then

> Nous allons dîner au restaurant -> **Où** allez-vous?

but

> Il sort de la poste ->  **D'où** sort-il?

- Could you please explain what is the difference between them?
- Why don't we use "*À où allez-vous?*"?
- Is it correct to say "*Où sort-il?*"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could you please explain what is the difference between them?

***Où*** means **where**. *Où allez-vous ?* : Where are you going?

***D'où*** means **from where**. *D'où venez vous ?* : Where do you come from?

> Why don't we use "À où allez-vous?"?

Because it is not idiomatic and the ***à*** wouldn't add any piece of information anyway.

Combinations with ***où*** are possible though, as Gilles commented:

***À partir d'où** la frontière commence ?* : **From where** starts the border?

***Jusqu'où** va la route ?* : **How far** does the road go?

***Vers où** partent-ils ?* : **Where** are they **heading**? (literally: "toward where...")

You can still use ***à*** this way:

***À quel endroit** allez-vous ?* : **Where** are you going (literally: "**To what place** are you going?")

> Is it correct to say "Où sort-il?"?

It is correct French but has a different meaning (where does he go out/does he leave).

Note also that like with my previous examples, the inversion is more a written or formal way to express the negation.

Usual spoken French would be: *Il sort où ?* *Ils partent vers où ?* *La frontière commence où ?* *La route va jusqu'où ?* *Vous allez à quel endroit ?*

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer here: https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/discussion/34632/difference-entre-dou-et-ou

I will try to gather the most important points and provide some translation hints.

- (...), où concerne le lieu où l'on est (Où est ton frère ? ) ou le lieu vers lequel on se dirige (Où vas-tu ?), et d'où la provenance, le lieu d'où l'on vient (D'où venez-vous ?).

*(...), où refers to the place where we are (Où est ton frère ? = Where is your brother?), or the place to which we are heading (Où vas-tu ? = Where are you going?); whereas d'où concerns the origin, the place from which we come (D'où venez-vous = From where are you coming?).*

- D'où peut servir aussi à exprimer une conséquence.
  (Il ne m'avait pas prévenu de sa visite : d'où mon étonnement.)

*D'où can also be used to express a consequence.*
*(Il ne m'avait pas prévenu de sa visite : d'où mon étonnement. = He had not warned me of his visit; hence my astonishment.)*

> J'ai repéré l'immeuble d'où il est sorti.
> J'ai repéré l'immeuble. Il est sorti de l'immeuble : il est parti de cet endroit.
> "d'où il est sorti" est une proposition relative complétant le nom "immeuble".

> l'immeuble où il est entré
> Il est entré dans l'immeuble (lieu où il va).
> "où il est entré" est une proposition relative complétant le nom "immeuble".

**EDIT**
(merci @ Gilles 'SO nous est hostile')

*It's a bit more complicated than this. There are other prepositions that can be followed by “où”, some of which convey a destination: “à partir d'où”, “jusqu'où”, “vers où”… But other prepositions need a “what” pronoun rather than a “where” pronoun: “dans quoi”, “sur quoi”…*

A general rule (if it exists) goes beyond my knowledge.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than this. There are other prepositions that can be followed by “*où*”, some of which convey a destination: “*à partir d'où*”, “*jusqu'où*”, “*vers où*”… But other prepositions need a “what” pronoun rather than a “where” pronoun: “*dans quoi*”, “*sur quoi*”… I don't know what the rule is.